# LocalDateTime and DateTimeZone.getDefault returning UTC time

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I am trying to set the date time of a local object.  Here is my code:

```
val date = DateTime() //returns UTC time
val dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault() //returns UTC
val localDateTime = LocalDateTime() //returns UTC
```

My phone settings are set to automatic date time, and my current time zone is Mountain Time.

How can I get the current time in my time zone (the one appearing on my phone)?

Answer (score 0):

If `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` returns "UTC", that's because the device's default timezone is set to it, so all classes will refer to it unless you specify another zone.

To get the date and time at a specific timezone, you can do:

```
val date = DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Denver"))
val localDateTime = LocalDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Denver"))
```

Note that **America/Denver** is just [one of the many regions that uses Mountain Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Time_Zone#United_States). That's because Joda-Time uses IANA zones names (in the format region/city), so you must choose the best one accordingly from this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Optionally, you can also change the default timezone:

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Denver"))
```

With this, just calling `LocalDateTime()` or `DateTime()` will use America/Denver as the default zone.

But remind that this will change the default timezone for the whole JVM, so think if that's what you need before doing so.

Comment: My device timezone is not set to UTC.  The Calendar object has the timezone of "America/Denver".

Comment: Then `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` is getting this info from somewhere else. Try to call `setDefault` then